# How to upgrade substrate polkadot-v0.9.20 version to polkadot-v0.9.24?

Tags: upgrade

How to upgrade substrate polkadot-v0.9.20 to v0.9.24?

Thank you

Comment: This is not quite a simple "do 1...2...3...." Solution. Please add more details about what you are updating specifically? Links to source help. Generically you must update you cargo.toml deps and account for any breaking changes that were introduced. Not that these are not semver compliant version bumps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some tips...

Look at the changes documented in the release:

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases

Note things like breaking changes, migrations, low priority vs high priority, client changes vs runtime changes, etc.

Also helpful to do comparisons between versions to see what the changes are. For example:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/compare/polkadot-v0.9.23...polkadot-v0.9.22

> You could do the same with the Polkadot repo

And most importantly -> Do one version at a time!

Pay attention to any changes in the `cargo.toml` file e.g. version upgrades

And make sure to update your dependencies to all point to the same branch of Substrate. For example:

```sh
git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24"
```

Build and make sure it works:

`cargo build --release`

Comment: Great. Thank you